# Topographical model of a wind-farm

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate-change

Has anyone ever built and tested a topographical model of a 200 mile radius with a wind-farm in the middle to see how much wind speeds and wind direction change when the farm is active compared to before it was built? Obviously it takes power to turn the turbines in a wind generator, and that will slow the wind speed, but by how much? How much per turbine? Will it change the direction of the wind as compared to where the wind flowed BEFORE the farm was built? Sounds like a good and SCIENTIFIC question on the "changing environment" to me...

Comment: Why is changing environment between quotation marks?